# Android Studio Layout Editor Looks Bluer After Update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

After updating to Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2 Build #AI 203.7717.56.2031.7678000, built on August 27, 2021. I got this render problem. Below I attached image there you can see preview screen quality its looks more bluer than before because of which I cant design properly. Any Solution?
[image]

Comment: Is there an answer? I have the same

Comment: Actually it's problem with screen scale. I put 150% in scale in windows that's why I got this problem. Solution for this to decrease scale to 100% but I have 14" screen so 100% scale doesn't look good if you got 15" screen u can reduce scale.                                                      **How to change screen scale in Windows 10** :                                                                     
 **Settings ->  System -> Display -> Scale and layout**